# update manager onVersion 13.04

Tags: updates

How to check for updates on Version 13.o4? there is a setting for updates, but how can I check manually?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get --dry-run upgrade
```

will check for upgrades, but will not change the system.

Answer (score 0):

To update, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get update  && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

What this would do, is to re arrange the package index files and Upgrade Ubuntu system including security update.